# ASP.NET Validate textbox during input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

On my page I have a textbox and I connected three validationcontrols to it.
Two comparevalidators for minimum and maximum values and one requiredvalidator.

If the user changes the contents of the textbox, the validation is not done until the user clicks somewhere else in the form. Either on another control or some space of the page.

I would like to validate while he is changing the contents with javascript as I don't want a postback on each character he types.

How can I can I call the requiredvalidators IsValid function from within the OnTextChanged event?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMoveSparesAmountToMove" runat="server" CssClass="txtMoveSparesAmountToMove" OnClick="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" OnTextChanged="**HERE THE VALIDATE CALL**"></asp:TextBox>
```

By validating during input I want to remove the validators text the moment the contents is valid.
In this textbox the user has to input a number. I he did so and then clears the box, the validation appears when the focus leaves the box. The validation does not go away the moment he puts in a number again until the focus leaves the box.
I got comments on that from the users, they don't want to see the red validation text as soon as they correct it.

Comment: Let the user finish typing before you annoy him. The standard vaildators can also validate clientside.

Comment: If the user typed something it means that required validation will be `false` right? Validating requireness on text changed makes no sense.

Comment: are you using validation control or javascript ?

Comment: Don't use the OnTextChanged event, use a JS function to check the text after the textbox has lost focus.

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter.  Take the example where the user is typing a decimal number.  For the compare validator 1 is valid, 1.0 is valid, but 1. is not, so as you type, the validation will not show, show and the not show again.  Quite annoying.